# Why FutureTask doesn't use AQS internally anymore?

Tags: java, java-8

Why FutureTask doesn't use AQS internally anymore in jdk8 as opposed to jdk7?

It is said in the jdk 8 comments it's done: "avoid surprising users about retaining interrupt status during * cancellation race"

I would like to know more about that use case and if there is an example of an undesired behaviour, this change fixes.

Comment: It says in the comment " /*
     * Revision notes: This differs from previous versions of this
     * class that relied on AbstractQueuedSynchronizer, mainly to
     * avoid surprising users about retaining interrupt status during
     * cancellation races. Sync control in the current design relies
     * on a "state" field updated via CAS to track completion, along
     * with a simple Treiber stack to hold waiting threads.
     */"

Comment: Sure does, I just wanted some more explanation

Comment: If you have a specific question or a specific point that you want explained, please update your question.

Comment: I just would like to see an example of why the jdk 7 solution was insufficient. Updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following scenario:

- Thread A is inside the `run()` method of the `FutureTask`
- Thread B invokes `cancel(true)`, which successfully switches the state from `RUNNING` to `CANCELLED` (before Java 8)
- Thread A completes the `run()` method
- Thread B, still inside `cancel(true)` interrupts the thread
- Thread A, now outside the `FutureTask` gets a spurious interruption

The new design fixes this by introducing different states for `INTERRUPTING`, set before attempting to interrupt the thread, and `INTERRUPTED`, set afterwards. Then, there’s the following method invoked upon completion:

```
/**
 * Ensures that any interrupt from a possible cancel(true) is only
 * delivered to a task while in run or runAndReset.
 */
private void handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(int s) {
    // It is possible for our interrupter to stall before getting a
    // chance to interrupt us.  Let's spin-wait patiently.
    if (s == INTERRUPTING)
        while (state == INTERRUPTING)
            Thread.yield(); // wait out pending interrupt
…
```

Note that this still doesn’t reset the interrupted state of the thread. This still is the duty of the caller, e.g. the `ExecutorService` implementation. But now that it’s guaranteed that in case of a cancellation, the potential interruption has been done when returning from the `run()` method, it’s easy to reset the flag. Without that guaranty, in case of a racy cancellation, it would be possible that the interruption happens after the attempt to reset the interrupted state.